# Flex: Prevent highlight on object with focus?

Tags: apache-flex

I have a TextInput object that highlights when it is focused...I would like it not to highlight when it is focused...seems like something that should be simple but I can't figure out a way to stop it? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the `focusThickness` style to 0.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it had to be easy!

Answer (score 0):

focusEnabled="false" will prevent tabbing at all if it not needed